# Create local conda environment with the databricks runtime ML 8.2

Tags: python, conda, databricks, environment, azure-databricks

I am trying to replicate Azure Databricks runtime ML 8.2 in my local computer so I don't need to start a cluster in Azure Databricks for testing purposes but yet have the same environment (dependencies). For that I started by exporting the dependencies from a Databricks notebook running `%conda env export -f /dbfs/path/to/environment_8.2_ML.yml`.

Then at my PC (Mac OS) I already tried running `conda env create --file=environment_8.2_ML.yml` but it doesn’t find some libraries:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0
```

I also needed to remove the build versión from each one of the conda libraries.

If any of you have a proper YAML file or have successfully achieve replicate databricks runtime ML in local computer, please help :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*at my PC*" - what platform? Those libraries are Linux only.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Mac OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the way to achieve this by creating a docker image and then run it in a Docker container, so the conda environment would be created in that container. Somehow, If I do the following steps but in my Mac OS computer (not doing a docker container but installing CMAKE with brew and then create a conda environment) it does not work.

Steps I have followed to be able to install all dependencies from the Databricks runtime ML 8.2 YAML file:

1. Get Databricks runtime ML 8.2 YAML file from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/8.2ml#python-libraries) (as @alexott mention in his answer)
2. Remove from the YAML file those conda libraries:

```
    - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0
    - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1
    - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0
    - libgcc-ng=9.1.0
```

So the YAML file will look like this:

```
name: databricks-ml-8.2
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - absl-py=0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - aiohttp=3.7.4=py38h27cfd23_1
  - asn1crypto=1.4.0=py_0
  - astor=0.8.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - async-timeout=3.0.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - attrs=20.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - bcrypt=3.2.0=py38h7b6447c_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blinker=1.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - boto3=1.16.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - botocore=1.19.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py38h27cfd23_1003
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - c-ares=1.17.1=h27cfd23_0
  - ca-certificates=2021.4.13=h06a4308_1 # (updated from 2021.1.19 in May 18, 2021 maintenance update)
  - cachetools=4.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - certifi=2020.12.5=py38h06a4308_0
  - cffi=1.14.3=py38h261ae71_2
  - chardet=3.0.4=py38h06a4308_1003
  - click=7.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - cloudpickle=1.6.0=py_0
  - configparser=5.0.1=py_0
  - cpuonly=1.0=0
  - cryptography=3.1.1=py38h1ba5d50_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py38_0
  - cython=0.29.21=py38h2531618_0
  - decorator=4.4.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - dill=0.3.2=py_0
  - docutils=0.15.2=py38h06a4308_1
  - entrypoints=0.3=py38_0
  - ffmpeg=4.2.2=h20bf706_0
  - flask=1.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h5ab3b9f_0
  - future=0.18.2=py38_1
  - gitdb=4.0.5=py_0
  - gitpython=3.1.12=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - gmp=6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1
  - gnutls=3.6.5=h71b1129_1002
  - google-auth=1.22.1=py_0
  - google-auth-oauthlib=0.4.2=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - google-pasta=0.2.0=py_0
  - gunicorn=20.0.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - h5py=2.10.0=py38h7918eee_0
  - hdf5=1.10.4=hb1b8bf9_0
  - icu=58.2=he6710b0_3
  - idna=2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - importlib-metadata=2.0.0=py_1
  - intel-openmp=2019.4=243
  - ipykernel=5.3.4=py38h5ca1d4c_0
  - ipython=7.19.0=py38hb070fc8_1
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - isodate=0.6.0=py_1
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jedi=0.17.2=py38h06a4308_1
  - jinja2=2.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - jmespath=0.10.0=py_0
  - joblib=0.17.0=py_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - jupyter_client=6.1.7=py_0
  - jupyter_core=4.6.3=py38_0
  - kiwisolver=1.3.0=py38h2531618_0
  - krb5=1.17.1=h173b8e3_0
  - lame=3.100=h7b6447c_0
  - lcms2=2.11=h396b838_0
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=h14c3975_1
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libopus=1.3.1=h7b6447c_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libpq=12.2=h20c2e04_0
  - libprotobuf=3.13.0.1=hd408876_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_1
  - libuv=1.40.0=h7b6447c_0
  - libvpx=1.7.0=h439df22_0
  - lightgbm=3.1.1=py38h2531618_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.2=heb0550a_3
  - mako=1.1.3=py_0
  - markdown=3.3.3=py38h06a4308_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py38h7b6447c_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.2.2=py38hef1b27d_0
  - mkl=2019.4=243
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py38he904b0f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.2.0=py38h23d657b_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.0=py38h962f231_0
  - more-itertools=8.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - multidict=5.1.0=py38h27cfd23_2
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - nettle=3.4.1=hbb512f6_0
  - networkx=2.5=py_0
  - ninja=1.10.2=py38hff7bd54_0
  - nltk=3.5=py_0
  - numpy=1.19.2=py38h54aff64_0
  - numpy-base=1.19.2=py38hfa32c7d_0
  - oauthlib=3.1.0=py_0
  - olefile=0.46=py_0
  - openh264=2.1.0=hd408876_0
  - openssl=1.1.1k=h27cfd23_0 # (updated from 1.1.1i in May 18, 2021 maintenance update)
  - packaging=20.4=py_0
  - pandas=1.1.3=py38he6710b0_0
  - paramiko=2.7.2=py_0
  - parso=0.7.0=py_0
  - patsy=0.5.1=py38_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pillow=8.0.1=py38he98fc37_0
  - pip=20.2.4=py38h06a4308_0
  - plotly=4.14.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.8=py_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.8=0
  - protobuf=3.13.0.1=py38he6710b0_1
  - psutil=5.7.2=py38h7b6447c_0
  - psycopg2=2.8.5=py38h3c74f83_1
  - ptyprocess=0.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.8=py_0
  - pycparser=2.20=py_2
  - pygments=2.7.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyjwt=1.7.1=py38_0
  - pynacl=1.4.0=py38h7b6447c_1
  - pyodbc=4.0.30=py38he6710b0_0
  - pyopenssl=19.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - python=3.8.8=hdb3f193_4 # (updated from 3.8.5 in May 18, 2021 maintenance update)
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-editor=1.0.4=py_0
  - pytorch=1.8.1=py3.8_cpu_0
  - pytz=2020.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyzmq=19.0.2=py38he6710b0_1
  - readline=8.0=h7b6447c_0
  - regex=2020.10.15=py38h7b6447c_0
  - requests=2.24.0=py_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=py_0
  - retrying=1.3.3=py_2
  - rsa=4.7.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - s3transfer=0.3.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - scikit-learn=0.23.2=py38h0573a6f_0
  - scipy=1.5.2=py38h0b6359f_0
  - setuptools=50.3.1=py38h06a4308_1
  - simplejson=3.17.2=py38h27cfd23_2
  - six=1.15.0=py38h06a4308_0
  - smmap=3.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sqlite=3.33.0=h62c20be_0
  - sqlparse=0.4.1=py_0
  - statsmodels=0.12.0=py38h7b6447c_0
  - tabulate=0.8.7=py38h06a4308_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0=pyh5ca1d4c_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - torchvision=0.9.1=py38_cpu
  - tornado=6.0.4=py38h7b6447c_1
  - tqdm=4.50.2=py_0
  - traitlets=5.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - typing-extensions=3.7.4.3=hd3eb1b0_0
  - typing_extensions=3.7.4.3=pyh06a4308_0
  - unixodbc=2.3.9=h7b6447c_0
  - urllib3=1.25.11=py_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=py_0
  - websocket-client=0.57.0=py38_2
  - werkzeug=1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wheel=0.35.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wrapt=1.12.1=py38h7b6447c_1
  - x264=1!157.20191217=h7b6447c_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - yarl=1.6.3=py38h27cfd23_0
  - zeromq=4.3.3=he6710b0_3
  - zipp=3.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.5=h9ceee32_0
  - pip:
    - argon2-cffi==20.1.0
    - astunparse==1.6.3
    - async-generator==1.10
    - azure-core==1.11.0
    - azure-storage-blob==12.7.1
    - bleach==3.3.0
    - confuse==1.4.0
    - databricks-cli==0.14.3
    - defusedxml==0.7.1
    - diskcache==5.2.1
    - docker==4.4.4
    - flatbuffers==1.12
    - gast==0.3.3
    - grpcio==1.32.0
    - horovod==0.21.3
    - htmlmin==0.1.12
    - imagehash==4.2.0
    - ipywidgets==7.6.3
    - joblibspark==0.3.0
    - jsonschema==3.2.0
    - jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
    - jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
    - keras-preprocessing==1.1.2
    - koalas==1.7.0
    - llvmlite==0.36.0
    - missingno==0.4.2
    - mistune==0.8.4
    - mleap==0.16.1
    - mlflow-skinny==1.15.0
    - msrest==0.6.21
    - nbclient==0.5.3
    - nbconvert==6.0.7
    - nbformat==5.1.2
    - nest-asyncio==1.5.1
    - notebook==6.3.0
    - numba==0.53.1
    - opt-einsum==3.3.0
    - pandas-profiling==2.11.0
    - pandocfilters==1.4.3
    - petastorm==0.9.8
    - phik==0.11.2
    - prometheus-client==0.9.0
    - pyarrow==1.0.1
    - pyrsistent==0.17.3
    - pywavelets==1.1.1
    - pyyaml==5.4.1
    - querystring-parser==1.2.4
    - seaborn==0.10.0
    - send2trash==1.5.0
    - shap==0.39.0
    - slicer==0.0.7
    - spark-tensorflow-distributor==0.1.0
    - tangled-up-in-unicode==0.0.7
    - tensorboard==2.4.1
    - tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
    - tensorflow-cpu==2.4.1
    - tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - terminado==0.9.4
    - testpath==0.4.4
    - visions==0.6.0
    - webencodings==0.5.1
    - widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
    - xgboost==1.3.3
prefix: /databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml
```

3. Create your Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Install CMAKE
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get -y install cmake

ADD <your-yaml-file.yml> /tmp/environment.yml
# ADD requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN conda env create -f /tmp/environment.yml


# Get the environment name out of the environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate $(head -1 /tmp/environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/$(head -1 /tmp/environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)/bin:$PATH
```

And now you need to run the docker container (once you've built your image). Don't forget to activate the environment created in that container.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

[Release notes for Databricks Runtimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases) contain the valid YAML file that contains all libraries installed in specific release.  For example, here is the [YAML file for 8.2 ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/8.2ml#python-libraries)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @alexott but that was the first YAML file I tried before exporting it directly from the Databricks notebook and it gives me this error while creating a conda environment: 

`RuntimeError: CMake failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'`

Comment: this error message means that conda or pip is trying to compile some package, and this package requires the `cmake` installed - just do `brew install cmake`

Comment: ye, indeed. I did install it via brew but still getting an error. Specifically this one:
`ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - hdf5==1.10.4=hb1b8bf9_0
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py38h27cfd23_1003
  - intel-openmp==2019.4=243
  - xz==5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - libffi==3.3=he6710b0_2
...and many more`
That's why I did as well an export of the conda environment directly in a databricks notebook without builds, because I'm afraid it doesn't find any if the build is specified in the YAML file. Is there a YAML file which I can just use it to create a conda environment without needing to pre-do a lot of things?

Comment: can you try to remove `libgfortran` and other from your yaml file and try again?

Comment: Still same issue of `ResolvePackageNotFound` I think is due to the fact that the YAML file you provided in the link, has build versions next to each library.
On the other hand, I tried removing build version as well as those fortran and linux libraries, but it ended up with conflicts. Example: `Package cycler conflicts for:
matplotlib-base=3.2.2 -> cycler[version='>=0.10']
cycler=0.10.0`

Now trying to create a docker container with linux distribution and do it there...still no luck by the way...

Comment: sorry, I meant your original yaml, created from DBR itself

Comment: Ye, that's what I did as a second part and it is giving me conflicts with the pip packages (I provided an example of those conflicts in my last comment)